# Notation for second derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am confused with the notation in the following example:

> if $f(x,y)=g(x^2+y^2)$ then calculate $f_{xx},f_{yy},f_{xy}$

I'm thinking that if $x^2+y^2=t(x,y)=t$ then $f(x,y)=g(t)$ and $$f_x=2xg'(t), \ f_y=2yg'(t)$$ so $$f_{xx}=2g'(t)+4x^2g''(t)$$
$$f_{yy}=2g'(t)+4y^2g''(t)$$
$$f_{xy}=4xyg''(t)$$

Is this clear or should I use a different notation for the derivatives of $g$?

Comment: It's not that it's wrong, but if I were an instructor for this course, I would prefer consistent notation. If you want to use Leibniz notation such as $dg/dt$, then you should use the same for $f$. Alternatively, if you want to use $f_x$, you should use $g'$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2005833/prove-that-fracd2ydx2-equals-fracdydx%C3%97-fracddy-fracdydx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clear. Since $g$ depends on only one variable it may be easier to read if you use the notation $g^\prime$ and $g^{\prime\prime}$.

The notation $\partial$ is not incorrect but not common for functions of one variable.

Comment: thank you, I've corrected it