# Prove that $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ equals $\frac{dy}{dx}×\frac{d}{dy}(\frac{dy}{dx})$

Tags: calculus

I would like to know the reasoning behind why the following is true:

$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{dy}{dx}×\frac{d}{dy}(\frac{dy}{dx})$

Comment: Have $\Delta_hy(x)=y(x+h)-y(x)$.  Then we have $\lim_{h\to0}\Delta_hy(x)=dy$.  Try manipulating$$\frac{(\Delta_h)^2y}{(\Delta_hx)^2}=\frac{\Delta_hy}{\Delta_hx}\times\dots$$and observe as $h\to0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the chain rule
$$ \frac{du}{dx}=\frac{du}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx} $$
and hence
$$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d\frac{dy}{dx}}{dx}=\frac{d\frac{dy}{dx}}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d}{dy}(\frac{dy}{dx}).$$

Comment: There's something off with your second line. I don't agree with the way this is written: $ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dx}}{dx}$. It should be written: $ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy}{dx})$. You can also write that $\frac{d(\frac{dy}{dx})}{dx}$ but that's not as neat. Either way, there's a $d$ missing in your "numerator".

Comment: @Deepak, yes, you're right.

Answer (score 2):

A direct application of chain rule is easiest, unless one is specifically asked to prove this from first principles.

$$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy}{dx}) = \frac{d}{dy}(\frac{dy}{dx}) \cdot {\frac{dy}{dx}}$$